# kendoDropDownList loading bar not showing

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using a dropDownList to show some values in order to filter results on a grid.

I have use the 'change' event to see when the grid must be updated

```
$('#view-mode-selector').kendoDropDownList({
    change: onMChange
});
```

in the method onMChange I am trying to show the progress bar with

```
kendo.ui.progress($("#grid), true);
```

and at the end of the method when all is done I have

```
kendo.ui.progress($("#grid), false);
```

But the data loads and I do not see the progress bar.

If I remove the last statement (the 'false' one) I can see the progress bar, but it never disappears.

If I debug, It appears and disappears when the data is ready.

It is not an issue of the data loading too fast, sometimes the data takes 5 seconds to be ready. 
The data is already in the browser, I am just showing or hiding columns.

Kendo version v2016.2.714

Thanks

EDIT

on onMChange I have some ifs where I populate an array (columnsToShow) with the name of the columns I want to show (everything else will be hidden) then I call a function with this code:

```
showHideColumn: function(columnsToShow) {
        var grid = $(this.gridId).data("kendoGrid");
        var show = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < grid.columns.length; i++) {
            show = false;
            if (columnsToShow.length > 0) {
                for (var j = 0; j < columnsToShow.length; j++) {
                    if (columnsToShow[j] == grid.columns[i].field) {
                        grid.showColumn(i);
                        columnsToShow.splice(j, 1);
                        show = true;
                        break;
                    } 
                }
            }
            if (!show) {
                grid.hideColumn(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

That code seems to be very inefficient at hiding/showing columns, all activity stops for few seconds when I want to show all columns (after having hidden some), I have around 30 columns and 30 rows.

Comment: Do u retreive the data from the back-end with **dataSource.read()** function?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little misleading. Is the `#grid` element you are having difficulty displaying the loading icon for a grid control (as per the name of the element) or a drop down control (as per the title of the question)?

**If grid**

In order to show the loading icon I used:

```
kendo.ui.progress($("#grid").data("kendoGrid").element, true);
```

And to hide:

```
kendo.ui.progress($("#grid").data("kendoGrid").element, false);
```

**If drop down**

I haven't had to force display loading icons for dropdowns however there is an example [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-manually-show-and-hide-loading-or-spinning-image#Y_apWF417kKpicdUz0NUHg), noting the comment specifying:

> The element must have a position:relative style applied

Additionally further down, it is noted that the element cannot have child elements.

Comment: Thanks, I agree, it was a bit misleading, I am trying to show the loading icon for a grid based on a dropdown selection. I tried your solution but it didn't work. I can see the bar when I debug, but it seems to stop when I hide the columns using grid.hideColumn(i) (within a loop), is there a way to hide multiple columns at once?

Comment: Hmm, we used the above in our solution and it worked... Are you using AJAX calls to retrieve the datasource for `#grid`? Although not related to the initial question, it is possible to show/hide columns based on the [`field`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-hideColumn) value e.g. `grid.hideColumn("FieldName"); grid.hideColumn("FieldName2")`

Comment: The original datasource is called with AJAX. but then we want to show or hide tables according to the dropdown option. No further ajax calls are made one a user selects an option from the drop down.

Comment: So the data is being retrieved locally when something is selected from the drop down? Perhaps [this](http://www.telerik.com/forums/refreshing-the-grid-using-local-data#JqYqq8k6Nk2BRjcZv5eNng) post can be of some use? Additionally, it might help if you could share a little more of your code? Specifically the code surrounding `progress()` (`onMChange`)

Comment: yes, all the data is being manipulated locally when the user makes a selection on the dropdown. I edited the post to show the code inside onMChange that shows/hides the columns. thanks

Comment: I think you're running into issues because the data is being loaded locally.. Only other suggestion would be to use a [timer](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/ui#methods-progress) but, of course, this is not ideal but it is another option.

Comment: I will give it a try. Thanks for your suggestions.